# How to create half circle corner effect on the div

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to create a menu with a custom shape, but without much success. Can someone help me with figuring out the way to create this shape? I have already tried to make it with `::before` tag but I was losing the shape as soon as the div would get resized.

[image]

Comment: Try using 

    .div{
    border-radius-top-left: ;
    border-radius-top-right:;
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<style>
  .rounded {
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div class="rounded"></div>
```

Giving top and right border radius will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Might something like this work for you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> Test Page </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>

<!-- Modified from 'heart' shape:
 https://itnext.io/how-to-create-beautiful-shapes-in-css-a-teardown-of-3-shapes-purely-made-in-css-c3ac7cb99c4
-->
<style>
 ul { list-style-type: none; cursor: pointer; }

.heart {
  position: relative;

  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";

  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  left: 100px;

  background-color: tomato;

  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;

/*  transform: rotate(-45deg); */
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.heartMenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  z-index: 10;
}
</style>

</head><body>
<div id="heart" class="heart">
 <ul class="heartMenu">
  <li> Link 1 </li>
  <li> Link 2 </li>
  <li> Link 3 </li>
  <li> Link 4 </li>
  <li> Link 5 </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body></html>
```